# Unable to fetch data in Google sheet with countifs importrange function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I want the count based on multiple filters from another google sheet
How do I Do it using `countifs` function? or is there any other formula for this?

```
State Groups              Metros    Mini Metros Tier I  Tier II

Delhi               
UP,Uttarakand               
Chandigarh,         
Rajasthan
```

For above, using `countifs` I want the number of people for Delhi and Metros from another sheet.

Comment: Is the another sheet in the same spreadsheet or on another spreadsheet? Do you already know how to use `COUNTIFS`? Did you already try something?

Comment: Its in another spreadsheet.I have used Countifs in excel worksheet.But unable to use it in google sheets by linking it from a separate worksheet.I tried using the importrange function but unable to get results

Comment: Please edit the question to briefly describe what you already tried including the formulas.

Comment: =COUNTIFS(IMPORTRANGE("1Uak9iA3Sjl6ijstMNqCxLpuEJ2HiSgQq3UIddhByVZo","post!L1:L28000"),"=Metros"),"post!M1:M28000","=North".   This is what I was able to do.